# Space is not allowed mysql column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `testnew`:

```
    +---------------------+
    | v_id | name         | 
    +---------------------+
    |   1  | Productivity | 
    |   2  | Work Quality | 
    |   3  | Knowldge     |
    |   4  | Comm know    | 
    +------+--------------+
```

Which is added by admin and I am going to create another table (Expected)

```
    +---------------+--------------+------------+----------+
    |  Productivity |Work Quality  | Knowldge   |Comm know |
    +------------+-----------------+------------------------
    |                                                      |
    |                                                      |  
    |                                                      |
    |                                                      |
    +------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'CREATE TABLE new (',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
      CONCAT(name, ' VARCHAR(50)')
      SEPARATOR ','),
    ');')
FROM
  testnew
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

`Work Quality` and `Comm know` has space so I can't get output.

How do I fix this?

Comment: INSERT INTO... SELECT ? - although using GROUP_CONCAT in this way is odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opposed putting special characters in column names.  But if you must, use the MySQL escape character (a backtick) or double quotes:

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE new (',
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('`', name, '` VARCHAR(50)')
                           SEPARATOR ','),
              ');')
       FROM testnew
INTO @sql;
```

As a note:  The `CONCAT()` in `GROUP_CONCAT()` is redundant.  A little known fact is that `GROUP_CONCAT()` takes multiple arguments:

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE new (',
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '`', name, '` VARCHAR(50)'
                           SEPARATOR ','),
              ');')
       FROM testnew
INTO @sql;
```

Comment: -Thanks a lot..got it